# javascript self invoking closure's alternative usage

Tags: javascript

I need a way to rewrite a javascript variable which I have written.

Here is what I have:

```
var TEST = new function() {
     var a = 'a';
     var b = 'b';
     this.c = 'c';
     this.getC = function() {
         return this.c;
    }
};
```

I am not very comfortable with the new keyword in front of the function(which even jslint/jshint do not like much).

I do not want key:value pair notation, which can be achieved with this code:

```
var TEST = function() {
    return {
        a : 'a',
        b : 'b',
        c : 'c',
        getC : function() {
            return this.c;
        }
    }
}();
```

Please suggest any better way, other than the key:value pair notations.

Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u1w6m9tb/1/) depicting the above problem.

Comment: `return this` then use `.call({})` instead of `()`. That's the other option I can think of.

Comment: Why do you hate anonymous objects? =)

Comment: I feel its easier to work with the regular style :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/u1w6m9tb/3/ JSHint valid.

```
var TEST = (function() {
    function Test() {
        var a = 'a';
        var b = 'b';
        this.c = 'c';
        this.getC = function() {
            return this.c;
        };
    }
    return new Test();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it into a class:

```
function Thing(){
    this.a="a";
    this.b="b";
    this.c="c";
}
Thing.prototype.getC=function(){return this.c;}

(new Thing()).getC(); //"c"
```